# Javascript window.open showing , TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am calling a JavaScript function on anchor tag click , and after that 
I am opening a url in new tab, but on this its showing error as follows -

This is anchor tag -

```
<a href="" onclick='service_by_vessel(<?php echo $vessel['vessel_id'] ?>);' ><?php echo $vessel['vessel_name']; ?> </a>
```

This is the function -:

```
function service_by_vessel(vessel_id){
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "front_ajax_files/get_service_by_vessel.php",
     data: {vessel_id: vessel_id},
     success: function(data) {
      var service_id=data;
      var newTab = window.open('view_service?service_id=' + service_id
, '_blank');
     newTab.location;
    }
  });
}
```

But after this I am getting following error , Which I didn't understand .

[image]

Would appreciate any help in getting this resolved.

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of the anchor click

Comment: If possible use jQuery event listener, or `onclick='service_by_vessel(<?php echo $vessel['vessel_id'] ?>); return false'`

Comment: Great , Its works using event.defaultPrevented(); Thank you